# Adding Forms Dynamically From Dropdown Menu Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails question about adding a dynamic form through a drop down selection rather than having individual buttons for each possible selection.

Right now, through the help of following some Railscasts, my application works where I have three individual buttons that are able to dynamically add three different types of nested forms to the parent, all corresponding to different models with different form partials.

The parent model here is a Workout, allowing traditional_blocks, emon_blocks, and tempo_blocks to be added dynamically using JS.

Workout Model

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tempos
  has_many :traditionals
  has_many :emons
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tempos, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emons, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :traditionals, allow_destroy: true
end
```

/app/views/workouts/new.html.erb

```
<div>   
    <%= button_to_add_fields "Add EMON Block", f, :emons %>
    <%= button_to_add_fields "Add traditional Block", f, :traditionals %>
    <%= button_to_add_fields "Add tempo Block", f, :tempos %>
</div>
```

/apps/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def button_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    button_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/workouts.js.coffee

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

Like I said earlier, everything works as I want it to when I click the buttons. However, I would like to be able to put "emon block, traditional block, tempo block" inside a collection_select with one button next to the collection_select that says "create." When that "create" button is clicked, I would like it to call that same helper(button_to_add_fields) passing along the necessary parameters for it to work the same way it does now with the multiple button implementation but using the currently selected association in the collection select.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `Ajax` for this

The Railscast you viewed, although helpful, is somewhat limited in the way that it will only allow you to add a single nested form each time

--

**Ajax**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :workouts do
   get "ajax_fields/:type", on: :collection
end

#app/models/workout.rb
Class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    def self.build type
       workout = self.new
       if type
          workout.send(type).build
       else
          workout.tempos.build
          workout.traditionals.build
          workout.emons.build
       end
    end
end

#app/controllers/workouts_controller.rb
Class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
   def ajax_update
       @workout = Workout.build params[:type]
       render "form", layout: !request.xhr?
   end
end

#app/views/workouts/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @workout do |f| %>
   <%= render "fields", locals: { f: f  }, onject: params[:type] %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/workouts/_fields.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for type.to_sym, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |t| %>
    <%= t.text_field :your_field %>
<% end %>

#app/views/workouts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @workout do |f| %>
   <%= render: "fields", locals: { f: f}, collection: ["tempos", "traditionals", "emons"], as: :type %>
   <%= ... dropdown code ...%>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

This will allow you to send the following `ajax` request:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/workouts.js.coffee
$(document).on 'change', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  type = $(this).val
  $.ajax
     url: "/workouts/ajax_fields/" + type,
     success: function(data) {
        $("form").append(data); // will have to work this out properly
     }
});
```

This should give you the ability to append the extra fields you need to the application, which will then come back with the appropriate HTML for you to append to your DOM

Hopefully you can appreciate the sentiment here - it might not work right out of the box!